# PrimeNg datatable scrollbar header margin

Tags: css, angular, primeng

They detect and set the right margin on the header only on initial init. Piece of code from their source:

```
    let scrollBarWidth = this.domHandler.calculateScrollbarWidth();
    if(!this.frozen)
        this.scrollHeaderBox.style.marginRight = scrollBarWidth + 'px';            
    else
        this.scrollBody.style.paddingBottom = scrollBarWidth + 'px';
```

It does not update when data is loaded later or if pagination pages option is used.

If the grid is initially visible on page load - it won't add scrollbar and after data is loaded and vertical scrollbar becomes visible, header gets misaligned.

If the grid is on a different route and navigated to later - the header has a margin.
If data does not overflow, margin does not get updated and  header gets misaligned.

Has anyone found a way to fix it or work around the problem?